# Can I dynamically choose the method applied on a pandas Resampler object?

Tags: python, pandas, getattr, pandas-resample

I am trying to create a function which resamples time series data in `pandas`.  I would like to have the option to specify the type of aggregation that occurs depending on what type of data I am sending through (i.e. for some data, taking the sum of each bin is appropriate, while for others, taking the mean is needed, etc.).  For example data like these:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dr = pd.date_range('01-01-2020', '01-03-2020', freq='1H')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(dr)), index=dr)
```

I could have a function like this:

```
def process(df, freq='3H', method='sum'):
    r = df.resample(freq)
    if method == 'sum':
        r = r.sum()
    elif method == 'mean':
        r = r.mean()
    #...
    #more options
    #...
    return r
```

For a small amount of aggregation methods, this is fine, but seems like it could be tedious if I wanted to select from [all of the possible choices](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/resampling.html).

I was hoping to use `getattr` to implement [something like this post](https://medium.com/@adriennedomingus/python-using-getattr-for-properties-and-methods-22a27e931a4e) (under "Putting it to work: generalizing method calls").  However, I can't find a way to do this:

```
def process2(df, freq='3H', method='sum'):
    r = df.resample(freq)
    foo = getattr(r, method)
    return r.foo()

#fails with:
#AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndexResampler' object has no attribute 'foo'

def process3(df, freq='3H', method='sum'):
    r = df.resample(freq)
    foo = getattr(r, method)
    return foo(r)

#fails with:
#TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obj'
```

I get why `process2` fails (calling `r.foo()` looks for the method `foo()` of `r`, not the variable `foo`).  But I don't think I get why `process3` fails.

I know another approach would be to pass functions to the parameter `method`, and then `apply` those functions on `r`.  My inclination is that this would be less efficient?  And it still doesn't allow me to access the built-in Resample methods directly.

Is there a working, more concise way to achieve this?  Thanks!

Comment: Try `.resample().apply(method)`

Comment: @RichieV Thank you!  I somehow missed this when looking at [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.apply.html#pandas.core.resample.Resampler.apply).  If you answer I will accept.

Comment: Try it first and let me know if it works, I don't know if `method` can be a string or if it has to be a reference to the actual method

Comment: it works yes, and it is in the docs for `apply`.  As far as I can tell `r.apply('sum')` is the same as `r.sum()`.  By time testing they seem to be equivalent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `.resample().apply(method)`

But unless you are planning some more computation inside the function, it will probably be easier to just hard-code this line.